# Search in Documents Not Working For Typeorm, mongodb, nestjs

Tags: regex, mongodb, search, nestjs, typeorm

I have an app in nestjs, typeorm, mongodb. These are the versions

```
"@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
"@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.4",
"mongodb": "^4.6.0",
"typeorm": "^0.3.6"
```

I am trying to implement the partial search in mongo documents by this way, this is my complete service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ILike, Like, MongoRepository, Raw, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { City } from './city.entity';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(City)
    private citiesRepository: MongoRepository<City>,
  ) {}
  getSuggestions(query: string): Promise<City[]> {
    console.log('in fun, query', query);
    // return this.citiesRepository.findBy({
    //   name: Like(`%${query}%`)
    // });
    return this.citiesRepository.find({
      where: {
        // "name": { "$regex": ".*a.*"}
        // name: Like(`%${query}%`)
        // name: Like('a')
        // name: new RegExp(`^${query}`)
        // name: Raw(alias => `${alias} ILIKE '%${query}%'`),
        // name: "Alma" <= this works
        // name: new RegExp(query, 'i').toString()
        // $or: [{ name: new RegExp(query, 'i').toString() }],
        // name: {pattern: '.*a.*',options: ''}
        // name: { $eq: "Alma" }
      }
    });
    // not assignable to type 'string | FindOperator<string>'.ts(2322)
    
  }
}
```

All of the commented solutions doesn't work and error I face is **"not assignable to type 'string | FindOperator'.ts(2322)"**
This is because in entity, name is of type string and offcourse it should be, this is my entity file

```
import {Entity, ObjectID, ObjectIdColumn, Column} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class City {
    
    @ObjectIdColumn()
    _id: ObjectID;

    @Column()
    id: string;
    
    @Column()
    name: string;
```

There is an option available for me to move to mongoose but I want to stick to typeorm due to its verstality for all type of dbs
I am beginner in mongo and may be thats why I am missing some basics of it, but I am worked in typeorm before and have experience in it

Comment: I have the same issue its so annoying!

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem, found nothing on the internet, so I made a very ugly solution.

```
const ugly: any = { $regex: /a/ }
 return this.citiesRepository.find({
  where: {
    name: ugly
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing and found that it is very similar to mongoose.

this works for me

```
const ugly: any = { $regex: /a/ }
 return this.citiesRepository.find({
  where: {
    name: {
      $regex: new RegExp('a'),
      $options: 'i',
    },
});
```